# Can someone explain this magic?(scanf,structures,pointers) c++

Tags: c++

```
struct persoana{
    char *numePrenume;
    char *strada, *oras, *judet;
    int varsta;
};
void citire(struct persoana *p)
{

    printf("NUME si PRENUME:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &p->numePrenume);
    printf("STRADA:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &p->strada);
    printf("JUDET:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &p->judet);
    printf("ORAS:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &p->oras);
    printf("VARSTA:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &p->varsta);

}
void init(struct persoana *p)
{
    p->numePrenume = "ham";
    p->strada = "ham";
    p->judet = "ham";
    p->oras = "ham";
    p->varsta = 1;
}
void afis(struct persoana *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", &p->numePrenume);
    printf("%s\n", &(p->strada));
    printf("%s\n", &(p->judet));
    printf("%s\n", &(p->oras));
    printf("%s\n", &(p->varsta));
}
```

I really dont understand is it something to do with scanf, or printf or is a problem with ->,&???
Can someone explain [this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOwmf.jpg), why is this happening ?is because scanf? or because I'm not allocating memory? or wtf?

Comment: you have many pronouns without antecedents.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Yes, they are. And whoever these people are that consider them not to be are incorrect.

Comment: Why would you say that printf isn't cpp? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

Below is a minimally modified version of the code that will work. It's not the best solution, and it's more like it is done in C. There are comments explaining changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct persoana{
    // Declare members as char arrays (beware of the fixed size)
    // If declared as pointers, they have to be malloc'ated, maybe in the init function.
    char numePrenume[50];
    char strada[50], oras[50], judet[50];
    int varsta;
};
void citire(struct persoana *p)
{
    // For the variables of type array or pointer, they already represent
    // an address so "&" should not be used
    printf("NUME si PRENUME:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", p->numePrenume);
    printf("STRADA:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", p->strada);
    printf("JUDET:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", p->judet);
    printf("ORAS:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", p->oras);
    printf("VARSTA:");
    // %d used for int type, & needed here
    scanf(" %d", &p->varsta);

}
void init(struct persoana *p)
{
    // Original pointer initialization in your code was done using the addresses 
    // of string literals "ham". Using that, a write attempt afterwards to the 
    // dereferenced data would cause undefined behaviour or crash.
    // Now, having arrays, that initialization is no more permitted, 
    // so strcpy is used to copy data
    strcpy(p->numePrenume, "ham");
    strcpy(p->numePrenume, "ham");
    strcpy(p->strada, "ham");
    strcpy(p->judet, "ham");
    strcpy(p->oras, "ham");
    p->varsta = 1;
}
void afis(struct persoana *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", p->numePrenume);
    printf("%s\n", p->strada);
    printf("%s\n", p->judet);
    printf("%s\n", p->oras);
    printf("%d\n", p->varsta);
}

int main()
{
    struct persoana p;
    init(&p);
    afis(&p);
    citire(&p);
    afis(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `scanf` to a memory location, you `printf` a value and tell it what type of value it is (*eg* `%s` for `char*`, `%d` for `int`, `%c` for `char, *etc*), more like:

```
void afis(struct persoana *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", p->numePrenume);
    printf("%s\n", p->strada);
    printf("%s\n", p->judet);
    printf("%s\n", p->oras);
    printf("%d\n", p->varsta);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, the result is even worse, :) i get some weird letters

Answer (score 0):

The code never allocates memory for the fields that the pointers in `persona` point at. A program that calls `scanf` on any of those fields has undefined behavior. Calling `init` on one of those objects doesn't help, because it assigns read-only string arrays to those fields; calling `scanf` after that's been done also produces undefined behavior.